# Is Reboot Needed after registering a COM dll on server

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, amazon-ec2, com

I have Just Registered two dll on EC2 web server. And change my build platform target to x86.

But Still geting this error

```
Retriveing the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Failed due to the following error: 80040154
```

Do I need to reboot whole server?? Since other site are also hosted on same server.
But locally working fine with VisialStudio 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need no reboot when registering a new COM server. We do that inside our deploy sequence inside Azure web roles and it works just fine - a web role VM boots up, our scripts run, the COM server files are downloaded, `regsvr32` runs and then our code consumes the just registered COM server happily.

Something is going wrong for you. It may be that registration actually fails. It may be that the consumer and the COM server have different bitnesses.